# Find and activate a worksheet with VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array of sheet names. I want to copy data from another file and paste the data in the respective worksheet. But it doesn't find the sheet. It creates an error in this step:

```
worksheets.(sheets(i)).Activate
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub NewWorkshet()
    Dim criteria(40) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer      
    Dim MyFile As String

    MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    criteria(0) = 335
    criteria(1) = 336       
    criteria(2) = 337        
    criteria(3) = 338
    criteria(4) = 339        
    criteria(5) = 351        
    criteria(6) = 392        
    criteria(7) = 393

    Dim sheets As Variant        
    sheets = Array(a335, a336, a337, a338, a339, a351, a392, a393)

    For i = 0 To 7        
        ' Remove Filter
        Windows("firstbook.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$6274").AutoFilter Field:=17
        Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
        Worksheets("first").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$3339").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=criteria(i)

        Range("A2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Windows("firstbook").Activate
        Worksheets("sheets(i)").Select
        Range("B2").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.Offset(1, -1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Nilesh Please clarify. You have a workbook called "firstbook" with sheet names "a335", "a336", etc. and you want to copy come ranges to which book? Another workbook and create sheets with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Its treating Worksheets("sheets(i)").Select literally as a word *sheets(i)* not as a variable. So it wont change and it will not find your sheet.

You need to create a string for this.

Try add `Dim MySheet As String`

then use this in loop:

```
MySheet = "sheets(" & i & ")"
```

Then MySheet can be referenced and will change as you want.

Comment: As you suggested after this  MySheet = "sheets(" & i & ")" , I used Worksheets(MySheet).Select.. But it is not working. It's showing error at this step- Worksheets(MySheet).Select

Comment: Are you in the right workbook. This can cause trouble. Do you need to activate the new workbook? I tend to use ThisWorbook.sheets(etc.

Comment: It shows error when I use ThisWorkbook.sheets(sheets(i)).Select

Comment: Try ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MySheet).Select where mysheet is the string which is the name of the sheet. I see they are not Sheet1, Sheet 2 but you now explain they are a335, etc. which was where my initial confusion came in. I thought you were looping through default sheet names (although they start at 1 not 0).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that

```
Worksheets("sheets(i)").Select
```

is looking for a worksheet called "sheets(i)" as a text/name.
If you use instead

```
Worksheets(sheets(i)).Select
```

then it is looking for a workhseet called like the value of the variable/array `sheets(i)`

Comment: @Peh Thanks a lot for guide suggestion. I will work on my code presentation and as you told I used this-Worksheets(sheets(i)).Select
 but still showing an error.

Comment: @NILESHSUTHAR If you don't tell **which** error you get (error message) nobody can help. And of course the array `sheets` should consist out of strings like `sheets = Array("a335", "a336", "a337", "a338", "a339", "a351", "a392", "a393")` and of course you need to make sure that these sheet names exist in your currently selected workbook (or select the correct worksheet). But I really suggest first to use the guide to improve your code this will reduce many issues you can run into. It's hard to correct a detail if the base is a bad code.

Comment: @Peh Actually my issue solved as I use the answer by TomW after a bit correction. I am really thankful to you that you suggested me the guide for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you haven't set your 'sheets' values as text.

```
sheets = Array(a335, a336, a337, a338, a339, a351, a392, a393)
```

The code should read

```
Dim sheets(0 To 7) As Variant
sheets(0) = "a335"
sheets(1) = "a336"
sheets(2) = "a337"
sheets(3) = "a338"
sheets(4) = "a339"
sheets(5) = "a351"
sheets(6) = "a392"
sheets(7) = "a393"
```

Then refer as follows;

```
Worksheets(sheets(i)).Select
```

Comment: After using this as you suggested How should I refer to the elements of my array? I am doing this--- MySheet = "sheets(" & i & ")"
Worksheets(MySheet).Select But this also shows an error. When I print MySheet it shows sheet(0) but it should show a335. How to solve this

Comment: That's weird I just tested my own code again and now it doesn't work. However, the code below consistently works to populate your array.

    Dim sheets(0 To 7) As Variant

    sheets(0) = "a335"
    sheets(1) = "a336"
    sheets(2) = "a337"
    sheets(3) = "a338"
    sheets(4) = "a339"
    sheets(5) = "a351"
    sheets(6) = "a392"
    sheets(7) = "a393"

Then refer as follows;

    Worksheets(sheets(i)).Select

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. MySheet refers to "a335" when i use MySheet = sheets(i) But it shows error in Worksheets(MySheet).Select... How should I solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still showing error in this step- Worksheets(sheets(i)).Select

Comment: sorry for late response. As you suggested I use my array data and it works. Thanks. I had some problem with sheet names which I had solved.